# Favorite a question but no up-vote?

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes

I have seen several people clicking on that little star (favorite) below the question and not *up-voting* it.

What am I supposed to make of this? Your question is really good, so I will favorite it but will not up-vote it *because*?

(This question has been asked solely out of curiosity).

Comment: Upvotes are a limited resource. Stars are not.

Comment: Usually I use the favorite because I am curious about the solution to the problem or it is something I am learning about.

Comment: i² : I starred it though

Comment: I favorite "bad" questions as often as good ones, really. I use it like one might think of Internet Explorer "favorites".

Comment: Let's just go all the way - there are questions that manage to be so horrible you just have to star them for how bad they are. Along with *down*voting them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starring a question can be useful for many things. Including:

- Tracking questions that you are thinking of closing, but you want to give the OP a chance to fix the problems you pointed out in the comments first.
- Tracking questions that are on-topic, but you really want to discuss the *type* of posts on Meta to see if something can be done about them because you think they might be off-topic. But you want to find more examples first.
- Tracking posts where the OP has shown a history of vandalising their posts, and you want to be notified if they changed the post *again*.

etc. etc. etc.

Starring does not necessarily mean 'I like this post'. Far from it. If I think a question is good, I'll upvote it. If I want to track a post, I'll star it. The two concepts are not otherwise related.

Comment: Ok.. This makes sense.. :)

Comment: Don't forget staring something because the solution is valuable.  The question itself might not be good enough to upvote, but there is an answer that is useful for future reference.  I do this all the time if I find something I don't want to lose.

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all. The star means "favorite" question, not "marked" question. I could theoretically upvote bad questions and downvote good ones, what's stopping me, right? It's just a counter, perfectly symmetric...

Comment: @einpoklum: right; so what's stopping you from creating a feature request to have the feature renamed? It's *just a label*. It happens to be very useful to track rotten questions as well as great ones.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: We'll agree to disagree on that I guess.

Answer (score 11):

It requires 15 reputation to up-vote. It doesn't require any to mark it as "Favorite".

People who *could* up vote could be marking it as Favorite for several reasons.

- They want to come back to it later to answer it
- They want to come back later to edit it
- They want to come back later to see if you've improved it before they do something else (vote to close, for instance)

Or maybe it's just someone who has the exact same problem and wants to see what the answer is.

I don't think marking as "Favorite" should not be construed as any sort of value judgment on the question *at all*.