# Can a question be automatically upvoted when it's marked as a favorite?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Can a question be automatically upvoted when it's marked as a favorite?

I just asked a question today that someone liked enough to mark as a favorite, but declined to upvote. I feel like I've been robbed of Internet points!

Comment: The majority of questions I've ever favorited were questions that I've downvoted.  (Typically because the question author was engaging in some form of abusive behavior and I marked the post as a favorite to check back on them later to see if further action would be required.)

Comment: You may have been "robbed" of down-votes. Be thankful and perhaps improve the question so that you will get up-votes.

Comment: It is generally good idea to search https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=favorite+reputation and read through related posts https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278200/favorite-a-question-but-no-up-vote/278203#278203 and add results of the research to the question... Otherwise you get votes for lack of "show any research effort" and for disagreement with proposed "feature-request" (maybe I  should as for ability to -2 posts on meta :) )

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Lots of people favorite questions, not for the question but for an answer on the question.

Favoriting and upvoting of a question will remain two separate actions.

Answer (score 0):

Favoriting is not only used for marking good questions or questions with good answers, but also it is the quickest way to track bad questions that require subsequent handling.

Sometimes to see whether OP improved the question and clearing down vote, sometimes to take further actions like casting delete vote when it is closed and not improved. Or any other reason you may think of.

So if you see down voted question marked as favorite, there is more chance that someone is standing in line to nuke it, than someone thinks it is greatest question ever.

Automatic up vote would certainly be bad idea.